# MVC C# DropDownListFor has value of previous select

Tags: asp.net-mvc, select, view, html.dropdownlistfor, selectlistitem

[C# fiddle screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ey4zR.jpg)

https://dotnetfiddle.net/MadhI5

Model:

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public List<SelectListItem> Sel { get; set; }
    public string Val1 { get; set; }
    public string Val2 { get; set; }
    public string Val3 { get; set; }
    public string Val4 { get; set; }
    public string Val5 { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var vm = new IndexViewModel();

    vm.Sel = new List<SelectListItem>();
    vm.Sel.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Opt1", Value = "1" });
    vm.Sel.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Opt2", Value = "2" });
    vm.Sel.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Opt3", Value = "3" });

    vm.Val1 = "3";
    vm.Val2 = null;
    vm.Val3 = "1";
    vm.Val4 = null;
    vm.Val5 = "3";

    return View(vm);
}
```

View:

```
@model HelloWorldMvcApp.IndexViewModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Val1, Model.Sel, "-")
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Val2, Model.Sel, "-")
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Val3, Model.Sel, "-")
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Val4, Model.Sel, "-")
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Val5, Model.Sel, "-")
```

The selected values are

- `Val1`: 3 (correct)
- `Val2`: 3 (should be "-")
- `Val3`: 1 (correct)
- `Val4`: 1 (should be "-")
- `Val5`: 3 (correct)

Look at the fiddle demo. Why Val2 and Val4 is not null in View? It`s a framework bug?

Comment: I think you should use `""` instead of `null`

Comment: You code needs to be in the question. And its not a bug, its just the way that the code works (caching the `SelectList`). You can make it work by using `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Val2, new SelectList(Model.Sel, "Value", "Text"), "-")`

Comment: Use "" instead of null works, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
vm.Val1 = "3";
vm.Val2 = "";
vm.Val3 = "1";
vm.Val4 = "";
vm.Val5 = "3";
...
```

Using "" instead of null works